# How to increase plane thickness using PlaneGeometry?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there any way to increase plane thickness or I have to use BoxGeometry in three.js??

Comment: you have to use BoxGeometry

Answer (score 3):

Plane is 2D object so you should use BoxGeometry.
[Documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/PlaneGeometry) is the fastest way to get answers on questions like this.